# how to read data in Sparks with a date column as index

Tags: csv, date, pyspark, indexing

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", True)\
   .option("header", True)\
   .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")\
   .option("index","Date")\
   .load(file_location)\
   .withColumn("Date", expr("""to_date(Date)"""))
```

but the index column is not date

Comment: Please provide a sample of the csv to help demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your current output and your expected output.

Comment: I don't see [in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) such option "index" available.